# QTableWidget - отображание выделенной ячейки цветом, если у cellWidget установлен иной цвет

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

У меня есть таблица `QTableWidget`, заполненная `QWidget` с помощью метода `QTableWidget::setCellWidget`

Пока в `QWidget` в `background-color` цвета нет, то всё работает хорошо — при клике на ячейку она выделяется цветом (на скриншоте слева - синий цвет).

Если же задать `QWidget` цвет (на скриншоте красный), то при клике на эту ячейку, она больше не выделяется синим (стандартным) цветом.

> Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на ячейку, в которой находится `cellWidget`, она всегда выделялась обычным (стандартным) цветом?

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 1):

решение конечно через пень-колоду (по хорошему вам лучше отказаться от TableWidget и перейти к TableView. С моделями все на порядок проще)

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->tableWidget->selectionModel(),SIGNAL(selectionChanged(QItemSelection,QItemSelection)),this,SLOT(myslotselectionChanged(QItemSelection,QItemSelection)));
...
}
...
MainWindow::myslotselectionChanged(QItemSelection was, QItemSelection now)
{
// тут покрасим то с чего сняли выделение
    foreach (QModelIndex idx, was.indexes()) {
        ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(idx.row(),idx.column())->setStyleSheet("background-color : red;");
    }
// а тут красим то что выделено сейчас
    foreach (QModelIndex idx, now.indexes()) {
        ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(idx.row(),idx.column())->setStyleSheet("background-color : blue;");
    }
}
```